# функция и ее параметры

Tags: swift, функции

Учу swift не так давно и есть некоторые не понятны моменты, а именно для чего функции, инициализатору нужен параметр с внешним именем и с локальным именем. Ответь те как можно понятнее и желатьно примером

```
   struct Celsius {
   var temperatureInCelsius: Double
   init(fromFahrenheit fahrenheit: Double) {
       temperatureInCelsius = (fahrenheit - 32.0) / 1.8
   }
   init(fromKelvin kelvin: Double) {
       temperatureInCelsius = kelvin - 273.15
   }
}

 let boilingPointOfWater = Celsius(fromFahrenheit: 212.0)
 // boilingPointOfWater.temperatureInCelsius is 100.0
 let freezingPointOfWater = Celsius(fromKelvin: 273.15)
// freezingPointOfWater.temperatureInCelsius is 0.0
```

Comment: что значит "с внешним именем и с локальным именем"?

Comment: это вырезка с книги "Первый инициализатор имеет один параметр с внешним именем fromFahrinheit и с локальным именем fahrenheit. Второй инициализатор имеет один параметр с внешним именем fromKelvin и локальным именем kelvin. Оба инициализатора конвертируют их единственный аргумент в значение по Цельсию и сохраняют это значение в свойство temperatureInCelsius."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не совсем понятно, почему "argument label" здесь переведено как "внешнее имя (параметра)" (ср. [оригинал](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Functions.html) и [адекватный перевод](https://swiftbook.ru/content/languageguide/functions/#function-argument-labels-and-parameter-names)), то же касается и "локального имени". Собственно по указанным ссылкам вопрос с параметрами и их ярлыками разъяснен.

Что касается вопроса "для чего"

- для различения сигнатур функций
- для удобства и следования традиции (здесь Swift наследует особенности именования в Objective C)

Пример

```
struct Celsius {
    var temperatureInCelsius: Double
    
    // 1. ярлык и параметр
    
    init(fromFahrenheit fahrenheit: Double) {
        temperatureInCelsius = (fahrenheit - 32.0) / 1.8
    }
    
    // 2. только параметр
    
    init(fahrenheit: Double) {
        temperatureInCelsius = (fahrenheit - 32.0) / 1.8
    }
    
    // 3. параметр с пропуском
    
    init(_ fahrenheit: Double) {
        temperatureInCelsius = (fahrenheit - 32.0) / 1.8
    }
    
    init(fromKelvin kelvin: Double) {
        temperatureInCelsius = kelvin - 273.15
    }
}

// 1
let boilingPointOfWater1 = Celsius(fromFahrenheit: 212.0)
// 2
let boilingPointOfWater2 = Celsius(fahrenheit: 212.0)
// 3
let boilingPointOfWater3 = Celsius(212.0)
```

Comment: лол. Это я по поводу адекватного перевода, так как я к ним написал и они выслали мне книгу (кусок того текста что я прислал), Спасибо за ответ пошел разбираться

Comment: @Роман если ответ устроил, то поставьте возле него галку